# What is this called? Login to other websites through your app

Tags: api, authentication, billing

There is an app that allows users to pay their bills in one place they are asked to log in to their accounts with various billers. Then it retrieves  their bill amount and due date and makes it available in the app. My question is what is the feature of allowing users to login to other platforms through your app called? An API or something else?

Comment: This is a little too broad for SO. But, in general, coding an app like this to conform with shared standards or custom interfaces requires an API. But it depends on the mechanism it uses. For all we know the app logs in using raw HTTP POSTs and scrapes the results for interesting values. Though, the nomenclature is not set in stone, and isn't really that important from a coding standpoint.

Comment: I think you mean OAuth or something similar which is designed for third-party authentication.

Comment: I think they would be using Oauth as it doesn’t store their personal login information on the server, unless there’s other token issuing services that could also handle that task